# How to pre-select a listview row?

Tags: android, listview

I have created a custom list view, I want to pre-select an item in the listview. I am tried many things on the net but no luck. What i am tried given below.

```
lvModifierSet.requestFocusFromTouch();

lvModifierSet.setSelection(1);

lvModifierSet.setItemChecked(1, true);

lvModifierSet.performItemClick(lvModifierSet.getChildAt(1), 1, lvModifierSet.getItemIdAtPosition(1));
```

This is my listview

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/menu_lv_modifier_set"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:divider="@color/colorLightGray"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@color/colorLightGray" />
```

Custom adapter code

```
public class ModifierSetListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ModifierSet> {

    private Context context;
    private int resourceLayout;
    private List<ModifierSet> modifierSets;

    public ModifierSetListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ModifierSet> modifierSets) {
        super(context, resource, modifierSets);
        this.context = context;
        resourceLayout = resource;
        this.modifierSets = modifierSets;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ModifierSet getItem(int position) {
        return modifierSets.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            view = vi.inflate(resourceLayout, null);
        }

        ModifierSet modifierSet = modifierSets.get(position);
        view.setId(modifierSet.getMenu_modifier_set_id());


        TextView tvModifierName = view.findViewById(R.id.modifier_set_tv_modifier_name);
        tvModifierName.setText(modifierSet.getModifier_set_name());

        return view;

    }

}
```

Comment: How about adding `lvModifierSet.requestFocusFromTouch();` before `setSelection()`?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท no luck, Actually the listview in a custom dialog box

Comment: @byteC0de , Have u looked on the below solution, please let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this with `Runnable()`:

```
lvModifierSet.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            lvModifierSet.requestFocusFromTouch();
            lvModifierSet.setSelection(1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to play the with `ArrayList`.Add the `isSelected` boolean parameter inside your model class like below:-

```
private boolean isSelected;


public boolean isSelected() {
      return isSelected;
}

public void setIsSelected(boolean isSelected) {
      isSelected = isSelected;
}
```

Inside your **`Java`** class, we need to the assign the particular item, which is selected or not.

```
YOUR_ARRAYLIST.get(POSITION_WHICH_U_WANT_TO_SELECT).setIsSelected(true);
```

And inside the `getView` method of the adapter class, u need to check the View is **SELECTED** or **UN-SELECTED**

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Get the data item for this position
            ModifierSet dataModel = getItem(position);
            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

            final View result;

            if (convertView == null) {

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);

                result=convertView;
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                result=convertView;
            }

        if(dataModel.get(position).isSelected())
          {
            /**
             * SET THE LISTVIEW'S ITEM SELECTED HERE
             */

          }
         else
          {
            /**
             * SET THE LISTVIEW'S ITEM UN-SELECTED HERE
             */
          }  
      }
```